# HDD spin down when not in use in FTP Server

Tags: hard-drive, ftp, power

I host an FTP server on my computer at home. It doesn't get accessed very often, but it does happen. I was wondering if it is ok to have the server's hard drive turn off when not in use, and then it can turn back on when it needs to do something?

The specs of the server:

- Acer AcerPower S285
- Windows 7 SP1
- 80GB ATA HDD
- 512MB RAM

Sorry if my English is poor, it is not my main language.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok, the OS will not give an error to applications requesting access to the disk while it's off, it will simply hold the request until the drive is available. These delays are normal and well-behaving applications should expect them.

Of course, spinning up a disk drive can take longer than usual, but consider that the FTP protocol used to work just fine accross the globe when <2kB/s modems and huge ping times were common.

Worst case, if the delay is so long that it times out the connection, I expect this would occur during on the LS command to list files and not upon logging in. So a FTP client might attempt to automatically retry the command, or the user can do it.

Comment: Most FTP servers would log the login (or even an initial connection). So even the connection/log can time out because of HDD. +1

Comment: Soooo, in my setup, it's ok? The time it takes to fully spin up is about 5 seconds.